# Why doesn't pandas daframe.shape have parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to ML and pandas.

I was going through a jupyter file of a linear regression program.
There I saw

`dataframe.head()`
`dataframe.describe()`
`dataframe.shape`

Why does the first two have parentheses `()` and shape doesn't?

I try to run `dataframe.shape()` and it give error `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.`

Here's a link to the documentation but it didn't help:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html

`dataframe.shape` looks like a function and functions should have `()`.
How to know when a function will not have a `()`

Comment: `shape` is attribute/property, not function/method of `dataframe`

Comment: Thanks @AndyL.   I didn't know the difference between attribute and method. But after reading your comment and below given answer, it is now clear.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `linear-regression` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes can have attributes and methods, attributes are .word, while methods are .word(), or .word(arg1, arg2, etc.)

You won't know in advance whether something you want to call is a method or attribute, but you will if you read the documentation for that class.  In that documentation, shape is listed under attributes not under methods, so you can infer from that classification how to use it (i.e. without parentheses). Here's the doc link for pandas dataframes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Make a habit of reading the documentation and it will save you a lot of headache!

Answer (score 1):

This is a Python question and not limited to Pandas.  Python uses parentheses as syntactic sugar to "call" the object you initiated the parentheses after.

Suppose you have some object `a` (this doesn't have to be a function, though functions ARE callable).  Then we "call" `a` by putting parentheses after it.

```
a()
```

If `a` is "callable" it will do something.  Otherwise, you'll get an error.

I'll define a stripped down `class` and show what happens:

```
class A():
    pass

a = A()
a()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-353-d08e164f0b26> in <module>
      3 
      4 a = A()
----> 5 a()

TypeError: 'A' object is not callable
```

However, I can make `a` callable by defining a method `__call__`

```
class A():
    def __call__(self):
        return "Hello World!"

a = A()
a()

'Hello World!'
```

---

So to answer your question, `df.shape` doesn't have a `__call__` method.  This is common for most `attributes` of class instances and is definitely true for `df.shape`.